# Getting ammo from dropped guns?

Tags: metro-last-light

Is there any way to get ammo from dropped guns other than dropping the gun your holding and picking up the other one? Besides this being tedious, it's buggy from time to time, as the my weapon I'd drop disappears under the floor.

Comment: uhh on the xbox you just tap X and it takes the ammo out of the gun, so at a guess just tap the pick up button, thats what works for me..

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you can hover your crosshair over the gun on the ground. It should show a bullet icon in case there are still rounds left in the gun. Press 'use' to take them out.

Answer (score 0):

Looting the body of the foe loots the ammo as well. picking up the gun will only give you the ammo that was in its clip. You don't get much ammo as you would think to get probably due to design/balancing.

Comment: That's quite obvious, but not an answer to the question asked. There's lot of extra ammo in the clips.

Comment: I didn't think you got any additional ammo from weapons?  Any I've picked up I've always had to reload the gun to actually put ammo in it.

Comment: @MattR: you pick up a gun, let's say AK, it has 10/30 ammo. When you drop it and pick up other gun, these 10 bullets get added to your total ammo.

Comment: @vartec well I'll have to try that out tonight, sounds like a perfect excuse to boot it back up!  Every day is a school day. :-)

Comment: No wonder I kept running out of bullets.